# How to use HM-10 as client, and send messages to specific services/characteristics?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bluetooth, ble

I have been messing around with this module, unfortunately i bought a fake one, but got the original firmware running inside it (V550).

So far i can set the **HM-10** up as **client/master** and by using an peripheral emulator on Android, i set up a **peripheral** as my **server/slave**

The peripheral is able to write to its own characteristic and it sends a notification to the client HM10 that fetches this value and displays it correctly on my serial reader (cutecom and arduino serial monitor)

After this, i'd like to write to the peripheral's characteristic, but **i can't find any information about this**, but it should be in the realm of possibility, i think.

I am using the Arduino IDE to interface with the HM-10 module.

Any information pointing in the right direction is very, very welcomed. Its driving me crazy now...

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade the firmware to V709 available on the [manufacture's website](http://jnhuamao.cn/download_rom_en.asp?id=1) and find instructions on how to update it. You'll need a USB to TTL converter or something that can act as one.

With firmware V709 you can use AT+FINDSERVICES? and AT+FINDALLCHARS? command to get the list of services and characteristics on the server and then read, write, notify, etc, on the characteristic you are interested in. It is outlined in the [datasheet](http://jnhuamao.cn/bluetooth40_en.zip). They call it self learn function and there's a document outlining how to use it.